# "No protocol specified" when starting Xorg via lightdm, but works when started directly

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xorg, display-manager, lightdm

To start the X server on boot, use of a display manager such as lightdm seems to be the preferred method. However, if I start X by starting the lightdm service, I get a "No protocol specified" error. If I run the same command that lightdm calls according to `ps -ef`:

```
sudo /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

(I added `sudo` as it doesn't start otherwise.) Everything appears to work.

A simple call to

```
sudo X :0
```

works as well.

Additional information:
This is on an Ubuntu 16.04 system and I am running everything remotely via SSH (**No X11 Forwarding**, xorg.conf is setup for virtual monitors, one for each GPU). When starting X manually, OpenGL acceleration and everything else works (tested via `DISPLAY=:0 glxgears`).

Comment: Did  you manage to fix this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: No, sorry. We never solved this.